# dynamically construct an array out of existing strings without new malloc

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, malloc

I want to dynamically allocate an array of strings.
So *arr* should consist of twenty pointers to the first character of each string.

For simplicity, each string is just the same, stored in *base*.
The first for loop should now create my array, which seems to work just fine.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
  int n = 20;
  char** arr = malloc( sizeof(char*) + n );

  char* base = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
    *(arr + sizeof(char*) * i) = base;
  }

  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
    printf("%s\n", *(arr + sizeof(char*) * i));
  }
}
```

The seconds for loop creates a **segmentation-fault** during the second iteration.

Comment: `sizeof(char*) + n` is a problem

Comment: `arr[i]` is `*(arr + i)`, not `*(arr + sizeof(char*) * i)`. You have to use the `sizeof` operator only with the functions that operate on raw data via `void *` pointers. In the pointer arithmetic above, the size of one element is inferred from `arr`'s type.

Comment: I hope you don't want to modify the things, your `arr[0 ... 19]` point to.

Comment: `sizeof(char*) + n` is actually a paste mistake

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Issues**

1. `char** arr = malloc( sizeof(char*) + n );` allocates (most likely) 24 bytes which can only store (most likely) six `char *`.
2. You don't need to try offset the address (`*(arr + sizeof(char*) * i) = base;`) by the base type.  The offset is automatically adjusted by the `sizeof` the base type.

The following changes must be made:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    int n = 20;
    char **arr = malloc(sizeof(char *) * n);

    char *base = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        arr[i] = base;

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%d: %s\n", i, arr[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

The preceding uses array notation.  You can also use pointer notation if you'd like. Change `arr[i]` to `*(arr + i)`.

**Output**

```
$ gcc main.c -o main.exe; ./main.exe
0: abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
1: abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
2: abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
3: abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
4: abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
5: abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
6: abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
7: abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
8: abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
9: abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
10: abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
11: abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
12: abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
13: abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
14: abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
15: abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
16: abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
17: abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
18: abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
19: abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

As recommended by [Swordfish](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3975177/swordfish) you should use the `const` qualifier on `arr` and `base`:

```
const char **arr = malloc(sizeof(char *) * n);
const char * const base = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
```

In this way:

1. `arr` cannot change (without a warning/error) pointed to `char`s.
2. Neither the address of `base` nor the pointed to `char`s can be changed (without a warning/error).

**Thanks**

To [Tim Randall](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9829403/tim-randall) for catching a math error.